# Apache can't read anything from mod_wsgi.so

Tags: apache, python-2.7, wsgi, graphite

I'm using Apache2.2 on WIndows 7. I tried to load mod_wsgi.so to Apache2.2 by adding the following line to httpd.conf:

```
LoadModule wsgi_module modules/mod_wsgi.so
```

In httpd.conf, there's some lines using directives from mod_wsgi.so (maybe depend on this so, I'm not sure) like this line:

```
WSGISocketPrefix D:\tool\apache2.2\conf
```

This line made me stuck by the following error which I get from Apache2.2 log:

```
[Thu Jul 25 21:44:25 2013] [notice] Parent: Received restart signal -- Restarting the server.
[Thu Jul 25 21:44:25 2013] [notice] Child 6436: Exit event signaled. Child process is ending.
[Thu Jul 25 21:44:25 2013] [warn] module wsgi_module is already loaded, skipping
Syntax error on line 20 of D:/work/tool/apache2.2/conf/graphite.conf:
Invalid command 'WSGISocketPrefix', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the
server configuration
[Thu Jul 25 21:44:25 2013] [warn] (OS 995)The I/O operation has been aborted because of either a 
thread exit or an application request.  : winnt_accept: Asynchronous AcceptEx failed.
[Thu Jul 25 21:44:26 2013] [notice] Child 6436: Released the start mutex
[Thu Jul 25 21:44:27 2013] [notice] Child 6436: All worker threads have exited.
[Thu Jul 25 21:44:27 2013] [notice] Child 6436: Child process is exiting
```

Please help me!!

Answer (score 1):

The WSGISocketPrefix isn't used on Windows and you should not be setting it. It is only relevant to mod_wsgi daemon mode which is only supported on UNIX systems.